# What does "FG BNK" mean in a metar?

Tags: metar

Here's the KLAX METAR 2153Z observation:

> KLAX 102153Z 27010KT 10SM FEW002 BKN200 24/16 A2997 RMK AO2 SLP147 FG
>   BNK S-NW T02390156 $

Comment: I will put my money on "fog bank" without checking...

Answer (score 4):

It means [fog bank](https://images.app.goo.gl/AoeGK4oPBs6MZwjG9) from S to NW of the station, although it's not codified.

The remarks section (after RMK) does not always use official codes. In this case, BNK neither appears in the [FAA's 7900.5](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1030668), nor WMO publications.

To quote the 7900.5:

> **14.18. Remarks (RMK)**
>
> (...)
>
> Where plain language is called for, authorized contractions, abbreviations, and symbols should be used to conserve time and space. However, in no case should an essential remark, of which the observer is aware, be omitted for the lack of readily available contractions. In such cases, **the only requirement is that the remark be clear.** For a detailed list of authorized contractions, see FAA Order 7340.1, Contractions.

By checking [7340.1](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ND/7340.1Z.pdf), BNK doesn't appear on its own or with FG, only in GRBNKS and SNBNK. Since no contraction in 7340.1 was available, the manual entry was made in as clear manner as possible.

For completeness, if the fog bank had affected the station, the proper code that would have been used before RMK would have been BCFG (fog patches). BC is likely derived from the French ***b**an**c** de brouillard* (fog bank).